# Is there a counterpart of CF_SWIFT_NAME() for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, swift

Is there a way to fix a name of the method implemented in Swift for Objective-C?

A **Swift** method

```
static func convert(foo: Foo) -> Bar
```

in **Objective-C** becomes

```
+ (Bar *)convertWithFoo:(Foo *)foo;
```

while a **desired** name is

```
+ (Bar *)convertFoo:(Foo *)foo;    // without `With`
```

Going from Objective-C to Swift I would use the `CF_SWIFT_NAME()` or `NS_SWIFT_NAME()` macros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that with a `@objc` attribute:

```
@objc(convertFoo:)
static func convert(foo: Foo) -> Bar { ... }
```

From ["Attributes"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Attributes.html) in the Swift reference:

> The `objc` attribute optionally accepts a single attribute argument, which consists of an identifier. Use this attribute when you want to expose a different name to Objective-C for the entity the `objc` attribute applies to. You can use this argument to name classes, enumerations, enumeration cases, protocols, methods, getters, setters, and initializers.

Comment: Thanks, it works. It's often hard to find such a tiny thing in docs.